# How to prevent viewpager2 from turning page when a tab is selected

Tags: android, android-tablayout, android-viewpager2

I have a viewpager2 tied to a tablayout with many different fragments holding textviews, i don't want the user to select another tab if he hasn't completed some of the textviews on each fragment. So when a user select another tab i would show a message asking to complete the current fragment data. I tried to select the old tab when a user select another tab in the "onTabUnselected" method of the TabSelectedListener but without success. Here is the code, please look at the TODO comment where i would like to prevent fragment changing.

```
viewPager = view.findViewById(R.id.mypager)

TabLayoutMediator(tabLayout, viewPager, true, false,
    TabLayoutMediator.TabConfigurationStrategy { tab: TabLayout.Tab, position: Int ->
        tab.text = titles[position]
    }).attach()

tabLayout.addOnTabSelectedListener(object : TabLayout.OnTabSelectedListener {
    override fun onTabSelected(tab: TabLayout.Tab?) {

    }

    override fun onTabUnselected(tab: TabLayout.Tab?) {
        val currFragment= fragmentSet[tab!!.position]
        if (!currFragment.validateFields()) {
            //TODO: don't change tab, remain in this tab something like tab.aborselectedtTransition
        }
    }

    override fun onTabReselected(tab: TabLayout.Tab?) {
    }

})
```

Can anybody help me please?

Comment: Maybe something obvious like `tab.view.clickable = false` inside strategy for right tab + create new /reattach TabLayoutMediator when needed?

Comment: tried to detach TabLayoutMediator, but i don't well how to do it

Comment: Add my code where you have `tab.text = titles[position]` based on current tab and validation result... And reattach

Comment: unfortunately doesn't work, it looses tab selection and you can't change tab anymore so you can resubmit your fragment data,,,

Answer (score 1):

I solved on my own, instead of using onTabUnselected it's better to use a listener on onTouch event, this way you can prevent viewpager to change page just returning true from onTouchListener. Please vote me if you like it.

> ```
> viewPager = view.findViewById(R.id.mypager)
>
> TabLayoutMediator(tabLayout, viewPager, true, false,
>     TabLayoutMediator.TabConfigurationStrategy { tab: TabLayout.Tab, position: Int ->
>                 tab.text = titles[position]
>                 tab.view.setOnTouchListener { v, event -> onTabLayoutTouch(v,event) }
>  }).attach()
>
> private fun onTabLayoutTouch(view:View, event:MotionEvent):Boolean {
>     val viewTab = view as TabLayout.TabView
>     val tabIndex = viewTab.tab?.position?:-1
>
>     var validationOk = true
>
>     if (event.action == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN ) {
>
>         val currFragment = fragmentSet[viewPager.currentItem]
>
>         if (viewPager.currentItem!=tabIndex) {
>             val validation = currFragment.validateFields()
>             if (!validation.validationResult && event.action==MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN) {
>                 showMessage(context, "Compila i dati obbligatori.\n ${validation.message}")
>                 validationOk = false
>             }
>         }
>     }
>     return !validationOk
> }
> ```